# Inconsistent footnotes

Tags: footnotes

I want to include footnotes in my paper, and I have added them, but the little symbol to actually denote the footnote differs depending on the page. How can I fix this?

Here is my MWE for the first instance:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\footnote{Murphy 1999 reveals etc.}.
```

And for the second instance:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

    \usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
    \usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
    \renewcommand\theadgape{}
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{textcomp}

\footnote{Optimal compensation contracts could result etc.}
```

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is not a MWE, consider to use `\usepackage{lipsum}` to put some dummy text and dont forget the `\begin{document} contents \end{document}.. `, to be able to find the errors.

Answer (score 1):

These symbols are given by the package [footmisc](https://ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) `\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}` try to put this line as a comment and compile.

Comment: "try to put this line as a comment and compile" what do you mean by this? Also, I already have included \usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, try to compile without that package, bacause is the one that modifies the foot notes and places symbols instead of numbers.